# Animate a character from video

Tags: animation

I have a skeleton I am trying to animate. I have obtained reference videos of a model going through the motions I want to animate. Is there a way to use the reference videos the same way as putting images on a plane to do poses?

I've done a few searches, but most of the questions on this topic are almost a decade old, hoping to find a way to do this in Blender if it exists...

Answer (score 0):

You can just drag and drop a video from your file system into blender. That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. You can create a plane and drag a video from your files into it. If you then press play on the time bar below the video on the plane will start playing.
2. This what I would personally recommend:
   take screenshots of the key poses of your reference videos then add them as reference pictures in you blender file and start copying the poses from them to your skeleton.